# Convert array of objects to sql query insert into

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to convert an array of objects to use it to do a query `INSERT INTO`

This is the array:

```
 [{ topicId: 4, provider: 'ex', postId: 'tT-t1IfwuyI' },
  { topicId: 4, provider: 'ex2', postId: '1382658099542084903' },
  { topicId: 4, provider: 'ex3', postId: 'BdePFBBBUdI' },
  { topicId: 4, provider: 'ex', postId: '-7UZr-wpL_Y' }]
```

I'm trying to do a map in array to do this...but its returns me just an array of postIds:

```
let sql = array.map(item => (item.topicId.toString(), item.provider.toString(), item.postId.toString()))
```

the result expect is a string:

```
( topicId: 4, provider: 'ex', postId: 'tT-t1IfwuyI' ),
      ( topicId: 4, provider: 'ex2', postId: '1382658099542084903' ),
      ( topicId: 4, provider: 'ex3', postId: 'BdePFBBBUdI' ),
      ( topicId: 4, provider: 'ex', postId: '-7UZr-wpL_Y' )
```

Im want to convert them to insert in this query:

```
query("INSERT INTO table (topic_id, provider, post_id) VALUES " + sql)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: your expected string result should not contain the properties names, just their values in the right order

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem, when I wanted to send the query, mysql didn't recognize my strings because they didn't have apostrophe, so i solved it this simple way, based on Prince Hernandez answer.

```
const array = [
  {
idservicio: 1,
precio: 20.5,
comentario: 'hello',
descuento: 0,
total: 20.5,
estado: 1
 },
{
idservicio: 2,
precio: 20.5,
comentario: 'World',
descuento: 0,
total: 20.5,
estado: 1
},
{
idservicio: 3,
precio: 20.5,
comentario: '..........',
descuento: 0,
total: 20.5,
estado: 1
}
]
//In the string comentario item, manually add the apostrophes.

let sql = array.map(item => `(${item.idservicio}, ${item.precio}, ${"'"}${item.comentario}${"'"}, ${item.descuento}, ${item.total}, ${item.estado})`)

//array with items.
console.log(sql);


const finalQuery = "INSERT INTO pos.detalle_orden (idservicio, precio, comentario, descuento,total,estado) VALUES " + sql
console.log(finalQuery)
console.log("query("+finalQuery+")")
```

Answer (score 1):

you are close, using ``` `` ``` with `${}` to put the values, you can create the desired string for each item on the array.

```js
const array = [{
    topicId: 4,
    provider: 'ex',
    postId: 'tT-t1IfwuyI'
  },
  {
    topicId: 4,
    provider: 'ex2',
    postId: '1382658099542084903'
  },
  {
    topicId: 4,
    provider: 'ex3',
    postId: 'BdePFBBBUdI'
  },
  {
    topicId: 4,
    provider: 'ex',
    postId: '-7UZr-wpL_Y'
  }
]

let sql = array.map(item => `(${item.topicId}, ${item.provider}, ${item.postId})`)
//array with items.
console.log(sql);


const finalQuery = "INSERT INTO table (topic_id, provider, post_id) VALUES " + sql
console.log(finalQuery)
console.log("query("+finalQuery+")")
```

Comment: it is the string, actually it is a valid SQL Query string.

Comment: Yes you're right, the expected string result in the question is not valid SQL

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
var arr = [
  { topicId: 4, provider: 'ex', postId: 'tT-t1IfwuyI' },
  { topicId: 4, provider: 'ex2', postId: '1382658099542084903' },
  { topicId: 4, provider: 'ex3', postId: 'BdePFBBBUdI' },
  { topicId: 4, provider: 'ex', postId: '-7UZr-wpL_Y' }
];

var sql = arr.map(item => ("(" + item.topicId + ", " + item.provider + ", " + item.postId + ")"))

console.log(sql)
```